# Using Fromdata in AWS Lambda in Nodejs/typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda

I am getting an image in FormData in Lambda event (it can be either Base64 encoded or not based on the media type settings on the API gateway).
I need to call a third party service removeBg  - https://www.remove.bg/api#sample-code
where it expects something like this

```
formData.append('image_file', fs.createReadStream(inputPath), path.basename(inputPath));
```

How can I create stream from the received formdata?
I tried below code but didt work (means I am getting bad request from the removebg)

```
const encodedImage = event.body; //provided "isBase64Encoded": true
const data = Buffer.from(encodedImage, "base64");
const formData = new FormData();
const stream = new Readable();
stream.push(data);
stream.push(null);
formdata.append("image_file", stream, "some text");
const result = axios.post(removeBgURl, stream, config); //config contains headers and responseType
```

Comment: I think you only have to send the buffer